# Tornado ProcessPoolExecutor: how to limit the number of processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, tornado, process-pool

I am writing a REST server in Tornado. I use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` with a `max_workers` configurable parameter.
However, the problem is that it seems to not effectively limit the number of processes the way I want.
The code is

```
    def post(self):
        ...
        self.process_pool_executor.submit(_execute_scenario_optimization, self.project_name,
                                      self.scenario_name)

        self._generate_output_json_from_dict({"execution_status": "RET_OK"})
        return
```

I need `submit` to generate an exception when the maximum processes active in pool at the same time is more than, for example, 4. Do you have any idea?

Comment: In [Python Document](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=processpoolexecutor),it shows `ProcessPoolExecutor`  can limit the numbers of processes.How do you find it not work ?

Answer (score 1):

The pool executors limit the number of processes that can run at once, but if you give them more tasks than processes, the extra tasks just go onto a queue instead of raising an exception. There doesn't appear to be a way to limit the size of this queue, so you should probably use a [semaphore](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/locks.html#semaphore) to limit the number of items you add to the queue.